# Certificates, App ID and Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

For submitting an iPhone app to the App Store, we need to create Certificates, App ID and Provisioning Profile.

I often get confused whith these things (even after reading the Apple documentation on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH1-SW1)

So could someone please explain me these things in simple terms.

> 1. Can the same certificate be used for multiple apps (and both for dev/distribution) ?
> 2. Also I guess App Id is unique for each app. But can the same App ID be used for both dev/distribution ?
> 3. For Provisioning Profile, I think we need to create 1 each for Dev/distribution. Correct?

Please explain in simple terms. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Can the same certificate be used for multiple apps (and both for dev/distribution) ?**
No, distribution certificates can't be used for development, especially the App Store profile which can only be used to submit an app.

**2. Also I guess App Id is unique for each app. But can the same App ID be used for both dev/distribution ?**

Yes you can use the same app id for the development, ad-hoc and AppStore.

**3. For Provisioning Profile, I think we need to create 1 each for Dev/distribution. Correct?**

No, you can create a wildecard development profile `*` as the app bundle id. You can even create a wildcard AppStore profile. Only apps signed with this profile will not be able to use pushnotifications or InApp purchases.

Comment: Could u pls elaborate for the 2nd and 3rd points....like how i can use the same app id AND what do u mean by wildcard dev profile ? Any basic example would be ally great...A +1 for now..

Comment: Also with XCode 4, are there any specific changes to the process of creating these 3 things?

Comment: You can use the same App Bundle id for all profiles, like: `my.app.id`. A wildcard profile has a bundle id like: `my.*` or even just `*`. And yes the process is the same as with Xcode 3.

Comment: So when i enter or use * as the Bundle Id, i can use the same App Id for dev/distribution AND the same Provisioning profile for Dev/Distribution....Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but only if you do not use in app purchases or pushnotifications.

Comment: Ok....Sounds like a cool thing to do..yes, i do not generally have app purchases or push notif....so just thinking of creating 1 Global App Id, then 1 provisioning profile (dev) using global app id....And i would no longer need to go into the Provisioning portal (except for expired)...though i m still a bit confused about having only 1 provisioning profile for dev/distri using single Global App Id...can u pls elaborate on that and i will accept and close the question...

Answer (score 4):

You need one certificate for Development and one certificate for Distribution (new ones for every year of enrollment).  These 2 certificates can be used for any number of iOS apps.

A bundle ID is what identifies an app (not its name), so you should use the same ID for all versions and builds, including development, ad hoc, distribution, and updates of that same app.