# Adding New Version of App

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode4.5, appstore-approval

I am in a dilemma about adding a new app/adding a new version. Basically the scenario is that I have uploaded an app already onto the App Store(free), which is live. Now I want to deploy a Paid version of the same application. My question is whether I should go for

1. Add New App

   OR
2. Add New Version for the same app.

Users should be able to download the paid as well as free app. Please help.

Comment: select Add New App and set a price for that app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then add as a new app.
So that user can use free as well as free version.

If you add it using the same bundle id and certificate, then it will come as an update of the existing app with price for the existing users. Also there will be no free version for new users who searches for it.
That will not be a good idea.

So add it as a new app, so that there is two versions for the users.

Comment: Can I use the same certificate which I used for the previous app which is live or I have to generate a new certificate?

Comment: Are you talking about the distribution certificate ?

Comment: You can use same distribution certificate with different App ID'. But it's better to use different certificate. If use same certificate there can be issues with push notification and In-App purchase etc.

Comment: @Shantanu: this link will answer all your questions regarding [certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415021/certificates-app-id-and-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new app and set price for it. The old one (free) will remain untouched.

But make sure, you have different app ID and bundle ID for the paid version.